# How limit the login in another device by the same user with tank auth library?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, tankauth

Is there any way to limit the access to a page with tank auth library if the same user is logged in another device?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question, and I don't know the Tank auth library very well.
Assuming there's no default implementation for this, I will explain possible solution to what I think your problem is.

The way this could be done is by storing a session token in the database, and generate a new session token every time someone logs in.
Then store this session token in a Cookie (or Session variable if you prefer).
And every time your app loads, check if the session token is still valid.
If the same user logs in on a different device, the session token will change and therefor the old session will be invalid.

If you want users to be able to be logged in on multiple devices at the same time, but just want to lock the access to a single page (for example access to a webinar / screencast), you have a few different options.
The most simple solution would be to put a flag into the database with opened or not. The problem is that if the one closes it, it cannot be watched again.
A slight variation on this is to use a session token which is set when someone first opens the page. You store the token into the database, and store it in the cookie. So the first device that opens it, is the device that can watch.

Another solution would be updating a last_active field, and do an ajax call every minute to the server as long as the page is open.
If the page hasn't been active for 2 minutes, you can assume it's not active anymore, and you can give the other device access.

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you looking for has nothing to do with Tank authentication Library, it's in your config file located in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['sess_match_ip']= FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
```

change to

```
$config['sess_match_ip']= TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
```